# Scheduling: P||Cmax

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, np-hard

In the schedule problem P||Cmax given:

`n` - number of tasks to schedule
`m` - number of machines
vector `p` - keeps times of working for each of n tasks.

How is `p` is defined each time?

Namely, is it an integer or a floating point number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about classical problem, execution times are integers. Using scaling, we can expand it to the case of rational execution times - it's good enough for approximations of real problems.